# Read image metadata on Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, metadata

Is there any way to read an image metadata such location with an API 33 device? I'm trying to do it with "ExifInterface" but I get 0.0 of latitude and 0.0 of longitude. The image has metadata.

This is the function to extract LatLng from the image Uri

```
fun readLocationMetadata(context: Context, imageUri: Uri): LatLng? {
try {
    val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
    inputStream?.use { stream ->
        val exifInterface = ExifInterface(stream)
        val latitude = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)
        val latitudeRef = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF)
        val longitude = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE)
        val longitudeRef = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF)
        println(latitude + " " + latitudeRef + " " + longitude + " " + longitudeRef)
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
return null
```

}

Here is where I am calling the function, you can see I'm asking for READ_MEDIA_IMAGES before.

```
val requestPermissionLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
        onResult = { }
    )
val multiplePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(maxItems = MAX_IMAGES_SELECTED),
    onResult = { uris ->
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)
            val hasMetadataLocation = readLocationMetadata(context, uris.first())
            if (hasMetadataLocation != null) {
                viewModel.onEvent(AddSpotUIEvent.UpdateSpotLocation(hasMetadataLocation))
            }
        }
        viewModel.onEvent(AddSpotUIEvent.UpdateSelectedImages(uris))
    }
)
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!! :)

Comment: The provider who delivers you uries when you use pick -multiple- visual media strips off exif location information as soon as you read the file using that uri. This is a 'feature'. They call it a 'redacted' transfer. Those developers have already been cursed.

Comment: `'m asking for READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` You do not need that for pick -multiple- visual media. Remove that code. Confusing.

Comment: Further this is not metadata of the file. As it is part of the file. You better change to exif location information. Come directly to the point,!

Comment: @blackapps I've asked for read media images permission because i've seen a way on stackoverflow to require the original uri and then look for the exif on the original uri of the image but it don't work

Comment: What do you mean with original uri?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use API, here's a simple integration code using ApyHub's Image Metadata API

```
import okhttp3.MultipartBody
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody

val client = OkHttpClient()

val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
  .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("image", "image-name.png", File("image-file -path").asRequestBody())
  .build()

val request = Request.Builder()
  .url("https://api.apyhub.com/processor/image/metadata/file")
  .post(requestBody)
  .header("apy-token", "YOUR-APY-SECRET-TOKEN")
  .header("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
  .build()

client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
  if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
  response.body!!.string()
}
```

You can generate `apy-token` from [here](https://apyhub.com/utility/image-processor-extract-metadata).